# Style issue where URLs are longer than allowed width on mobile screens using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to resolve this issue without changing the URLs,

On mobile - the allowed width is not respected because the URL does not have dashes or spaces:

[image]

This is enlarging the width for the whole screen and causing for the user to be able to slide the screen to the left...

I know I could use textboxes and limit their limit, but I wonder if there's another solution...

**Is there some style that can help prevent that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add `word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word;` to `<a>` element.

Comment: Great it works! do you know if it should cover *all* browsers?

Comment: As far as I know it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the css rule `word-wrap: break-word` like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).